# How to listen to events with a Listener that has an injected service in Nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a listener which listens to events but I also want that listener to call on other services to do stuff as part of the event. ie create a db notification, send an sms etc.

When I create a constructor to inject the dependant Service the Listener stops picking up the events and when I remove the constructor with  the Service, it starts working again.

How do I need to structure this for the listener to be able to call other services such as NotificationsService in example below?

client-updated.listener.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ClientUpdatedListener {

    constructor(
        @Inject(NotificationsService) private notificationService) {
    }

    private readonly logger = new Logger(ClientUpdatedListener.name);

    @OnEvent(eventType.CLIENT_UPDATED)
    handleClientUpdatedEvent(event: ClientUpdatedEvent) {
        this.logger.log('Processing event: ' + eventType.CLIENT_UPDATED );
        console.log(event);

       this.notificationService.emailClient(event.id);
    }
```

The Notifications Service.
It's a shell at the moment but I expect to perform logic and possibly db calls from within it.

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationsService {

    constructor(
        @Inject(TENANT_CONNECTION) private tenantDb,
    ) {}
    
    emailClient(id: string) {
        console.log(id);
    } 
}
```

The calling service code

```
    const clientUpdatedEvent = new ClientUpdatedEvent();
    clientUpdatedEvent.id = id;
    this.eventEmitter.emit(eventType.CLIENT_UPDATED, clientUpdatedEvent);
```

Comment: Can I ask for NotificationsService? I think the Inject of NestJS should be 
constructor(private notificationService: NotificationsService) {}

Comment: @deko_39 I have added the NotificationsService class now.

Comment: If you use class, not custom provider, you need to get rid of @Inject() and make it like
constructor(private service: Service){}, @Inject('A') should be used for inject repo or custom provider(service) with the name A

Comment: @deko_39 So this seems to unblock the event. I can see event being received in handleClientUpdatedEvent. However this.notificationService is undefined after removing '@inject' from Constructor.

Comment: I think the issue is that Event subscribers cannot be request-scoped as per the docs. I injected tenantDb into notificationsService and it causes the event not to be handled from client-updated.listener.ts. So this means I can't store/access the database to save notifications when handling an event unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You'll notice in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events#listening-to-events) that there is an explicit warning that Event Listening Services can not be `REQUEST` scoped. If you need access to the request scoped service, you'll need to pass on the request information as a part of the event payload, and use the [ModuleRef and ContextIdFactory](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#resolving-scoped-providers) to generate the context id for the current sub-tree and then pulling the `NotificationsService` from that sub-tree.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of how this is done?

Comment: If at least one dependency (any depth e.g. dependency of dependency of dep...) is { scope: Scope.REQUEST }, nothing will work as expected with @OnEvent